# Specifying xlim and ylim when using log-scale in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to specify the lower and upper range for the x- and y-axis for a log-scale plot. I thought I could use xlim and ylim, but I receive a warning message and no plot:

1: In plot.window(...) :
  nonfinite axis limits [GScale(-inf,3.30103,1, .); log=1]

Here is my code.

`plot(FAS_set$ConcCalc~ZCS_set$ConcCalc,pch=21,bg="black",log="xy",xlim=c(0,2000),ylim=c(0,100000))`

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: What's log(0)? You're trying to set your axis limit to that.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. the infinity in the warning message should've hit me on the head...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

On a log-scale, 0 is minus infinity. Change your lower limit to 0.000001 or something and you'll be fine, eg this works:

```
 plot(1:10, xlim=c(0.001,10), ylim=c(0.001,10), log="xy")
```