# log and lim in ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

my question is like here

[Specifying xlim and ylim when using log-scale in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972105/specifying-xlim-and-ylim-when-using-log-scale-in-r)

but just for ggplot. How can I use xlim and scale_x_log10() to choose the size of the x region and then ylim() and scale_x_log10() for the y region. In normal plot it is done like

```
plot(1:10, xlim=c(0.001,10), ylim=c(0.001,10), log="xy")
```

is there a same qay for ggplot?

Answer (score 2):

For the `ggplot()` in this case you can use `coord_cartesian()` and then set limits. This will "zoom" your plot to provided limits.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10),aes(x,y))+geom_point()+
      scale_x_log10()+scale_y_log10()+
      coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0.001,10),ylim=c(0.001,10))
```

Comment: ok coolis there any equivalen to place a legend as topleft in ggplot? I need to specif coordinat by hand?

Comment: This is pretty good for legends: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Legend-Attributes