# Why is R^2 in linear regression affected by scale of x axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I'm doing simple linear regression, plotting, and adding the equation + R^2 to the graph. I'm having issues with varying R^2 values. This is my code - also, please excuse how it is formatted, I'm **very** new at this and messing with this gives me errors + I want to give you exactly how I've coded this.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)
ex_plot <- ggplot(data = dataex, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  stat_smooth(data = dataex, method = "lm", fullrange = FALSE) +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = x ~ y, 
               eq.with.lhs = "italic(hat(y))~`=`~",
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "*plain(\",\")~")), 
               parse = TRUE) +
  geom_point()

ex <- ex_plot +
  xlim(0, 60) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log10') +
  scale_x_continuous(trans='log10') +
  ggtitle("ex") +
  ylab('ex') +
  xlab('ex')
```

The R^2 changes when I include or remove the "scale_x_continuous" or scale_y_continuous arguments - 0.36 when both are scaled, 0.22 when only the x-axis is scaled, and 0.32 when neither axis is scaled. I am only choosing to scale the axes purely for visualization purposes; I could entirely remove the scale arguments, but this would make it difficult for the reader to understand the data. Why does the code I have written cause this? Is there a better way to write this code such that scaling the axes does not affect the linear regression?

Comment: I suspect this is an issue with `xlim()`, try removing `xlim()`and use `coord_cartesian()` to 'zoom in' on your plot instead (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33646378/12957340)

Comment: @jared_mamrot Just tried this, I still get the same R^2 values as I did with xlim()

Comment: Hmm.. Perhaps edit your question with a sample of your data (`dput(dataex)`) or create a  [small reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help troubleshoot

Comment: Using `trans="log10"` transforms your data before stat_smooth or stat_eq_poly is applied, i.e. you are "estimating" a log transformed model. Hence you get a different R^2.

Comment: Wow... Is this expected behavior? It took me a while to understand this, feels to me this is wrong, but maybe it is just a matter of preference