# Setting ylim in R with a log scale AND setting tick values

Tags: r, plot, axis

I found another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972105/specifying-xlim-and-ylim-when-using-log-scale-in-r) but it doesn't quite solve my problem.

I'm trying to adjust the **log scale for the y axis** on one of my box plots so that it ranges from 0 to 100,000.  (it is currently at 0 to 10,000)

I have been playing around with the correct limits to set to give me the y axis below. But it doesn't get it exactly right.

How do I set the log scale for another boxplot to go from 10, 100, 1,000,10,000,100,000?

here's my code:

```
boxplot(RESULTS ~ ID, data=ywater, boxfill=colors, 
        names=c(" ","Site L1", " ", " ", "Site L2", " ", " ", "Site L3", "     "), yaxt="n",
        ylab="Concentration (cfu/100 mL)", log="y", ylim=c(1 , 100000))
legend('topleft', horiz = FALSE, fill = unique(colors), legend =levels(y$ANALYTE), bty = 'n')
axis(side=2, font=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set.seed(42)
mydata = data.frame(y = c(sample(10:100000,200)))
boxplot(mydata$y, log = "y", yaxt = "n", ylim = c(10,100000), xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
axis(side=2, font=1, at = c(10,100,1000,10000,100000),
        labels = c("10", "100", "1,000","10,000","100,000"), las =2)
```

Comment: Thanks! Helpful feedback. I added your code to both axes, and started ylim at 1 instead of 10 so they are on the same axis. Otherwise, kept all the same.